# How to set priority of custom Oval constraint

Tags: preconditions, oval

I have a custom Annotation constraint , but I want it to be checked only if the other constraint is valid .For example:

```
@NotNull
private String propertyA;
@Digits
private String propertyB;
```

if propertyA is null , i don't want "@Digits"on propertyB to be checked.

How can i solve the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "when" attribute, e.g.

```
@NotNull
private String propertyA;

@Digits(when="groovy:_this.propertyA!=null")
private String propertyB;
```

This example requires the Groovy runtime to be in the classpath. You can also use another scripting language, see http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#declaring-conditional-constraints